# Use a virtal disk over shared storage, or expose shared storage inside guest

Tags: storage

At work, we have a system that relies on what I can equate to a flat file database.  It does what appears to be liner scans of each database file.  Naturally, our limit here is going to be file I/O.  This applications database table pages reside in the same directory.  While some tables are read frequently, others are barely touched over the normal course of business.

We are in the process of creating a shared storage setup (early stages, not sure the vendor or setup yet).

My question here is, would performance be better to expose a disk over the shared storage (like an VMDK stored on an ISCSI target or NFS share) or to connect to the shared storage inside the guest.

My assumption (based on my limited knowledge) is the latter, since the storage server could potentially cache the more frequently used files only, and not the whole disk, whereas the former would need to cache the whole disk, potentially taking up more cache and maybe more cache swaps based on cache size.

Comment: Need more information about the types of virtualization used for the guest and the potential storage system

Comment: Potential storage system is still highly variable.  In early stages of spec'ing.  For the moment, hyper-visor is vmware

Comment: In that case (as my answer suggests) at this time there is no case to deviate from your normal VM provisioning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your assumption about how caches work is flawed. They almost always cache at something like the block level, not the file level.

All other things being equal, direct access to the shared storage from within the guest will be marginally faster than through a virtual disk. However, the only way to know what the actual performance difference will be on your setup is to test both configurations and benchmark them.

Comment: So it's just my misunderstanding of the technology and how it works.  Thanks!  Any suggestions of where I should go to correct my lack of education?

Comment: Whether it will be faster or not basically depends on the virtualization penalty for storage I/O vs. the penalty for networking I/O, especially if raw disks are used (so there is no VMFS to take into account for additional overhead). I would think that for most cases it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Any caching of **files** would happen at the guest level.  Caching (potentially) of blocks occurs at the storage head.  In general, justifying deviation from your normal virtualization strategy should require significant benefits. It sounds like they are all virtual disks so unless you have evidence of significant improvements that would "cover" the uniqueness of the server, I'd stick with using a virtual disk.